# Gmail "New message in this thread" show up automatically?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, when you have a thread open and a new email comes in, you get a yellow notification in the bottom right telling you when a new email has arrived.

Is there any way to automatically load the new email and bypass this notification?

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting in Gmail that would do that, no.

I suppose something like a Greasemonkey script *might* be crafted to do something like that.

Comment: The new Inbox by Gmail might already do that, but I haven't been able to test it.